# how to jms as a json format (SyndEntryImpl)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

This is my spring integration configuration:

```
 <int-feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="feedAdapter"
                                      channel="feedChannel"
                                      auto-startup="true"
                                      url="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/49479712">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
    </int-feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="feedChannel"/>

    <int:chain input-channel="feedChannel" output-channel="feedOutputChannel">
        <int:transformer id="transformer"
                         expression="@confbean"/>
        <int:object-to-json-transformer/>
    </int:chain>

    <bean id="confbean" class="com.xml.urlfeed.Feed">
        <property name="title" value="payload.title" />
        <property name="author" value="payload.author" />
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="feedOutputChannel"/>

    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOutGateway"
                                  channel="feedOutputChannel"
                                  destination="inputQueue"/>
```

```
public class Feed {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Some entries from feed xml.

```
SyndEntryImpl.title=Test123
SyndEntryImpl.authors[0].name=Quentin
```

Basically I want this to send to activemq queue as a json format.

What message I achieved with my spring configuration:

```
{"title":"payload.title","author":"payload.author"}
```

But this is not result I want. This is how I want it to be:

```
{"title":"Test123","author":"Quentin"}
```

How do I need to declare this from SyndEntryImpl to title and author that I could send it to activemq as json format and later on I would able to consume this message as json format and transform it to object?

I believe that I need to fix this to make it work:

```
<property name="title" value="payload.title" />
<property name="author" value="payload.author" />
```

But how do I change `value`? That it would work with SyndEntryImpl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bean is static; you need to use something like this...

```java
expression="new com.foo.Feed(payload.title, payload.author)"
```

...by adding a constructor.